# ScalaJS. How to exclude submodules from the resulting output js file?

Tags: scala.js

I have a front end application from the chain of three modules A, B and C. B depends on A. C depends on B and A. Each module has own sbt file for building the js file. Some application pages use only A, other A and B, other A, B and C. SBT file of module C looks like this.

```
name := "C"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"

lazy val A = RootProject(file("../A"))
lazy val B = RootProject(file("../B"))
val main = Project(id = "C", base = file(".")).dependsOn(A).dependsOn(B)

enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
```

The problem is that the "sbt fullOptJS" creates a js file in which the definitions from A and B are duplicated. I want the file created for module C to use the files already loaded to the browser for modules A and B, and not to repeat them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible. See https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/2681 and https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/2833 for some context.